# Waiting a state change before trigg new route with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to wait a promise resolve before trigg new route with react-router ?

I need to wait a state change before follow the new route. Using push history works if we handle our function to onClick(), but it's not working if we trigg by another way.

Any suggestion about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That's where the React LifeCycle Method `ComponentDiDUpdate(){}` comes handy or if you are using React Hooks, you can use `useEffect(() => {}, []);`

Here are the links:

[Use Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

[componentDidUpdate()](https://medium.com/@julienrioux/how-to-use-react-component-lifecycle-970d9a917220)